# Amibroker AFL first 15min candle High

Tags: amibroker

I want to find high of the first 15 min candle.

I am using the below code.

```
bi = BarIndex();
arrayitem = SelectedValue(bi) -bi[0];
firstbarHigh = High[arrayitem ];
```

This code is giving me the CLOSE price for the 1st candle. I want High price of the first 15min candle.

Plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
 newday = Day() != Ref(Day(),-1);  //check if new day or not
 starttime = ValueWhen(newday,TimeNum());
 IBendtime = starttime+1500;
 minh = ValueWhen(newday,TimeFrameGetPrice("H",in5Minute*3));
 minl = ValueWhen(newday,TimeFrameGetPrice("L",in5Minute*3));
```